# Axios + query-string

Tags: javascript, axios, query-string

I was wondering how I would be able to use query-string npm package to ease my axios calls. The package I use is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string

An example:

```js
import qs from 'query-string';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/products${qs.parse({ offset: 0, limit: 12 })}`);
```

Not sure why but this does not work as expected.

Comment: _“Not sure why but this does not work as expected”_ - because you’re going in exactly the wrong direction … `parse` parses an existing query string into the corresponding data structure - you want the opposite, you want to create the query string from your data structure. The method to do that, is `queryString.stringify`.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much @04FS ! Totally forgot that method. Cheers and have an awesome week ahead man!

Comment: Mobile devices can indeed produce backticks. On Android you can find the symbol keyboard, and then do a long-press on the apostrophe to get a menu to choose from several apostrophe-like symbols. Please repair this at the earliest opportunity, and for new questions, please do not post if you know you cannot format it correctly.

Answer (score 18):

You don't really need it. `Axios` has a standard way to put params into your request without any additional libraries or doing something manually.

```js
axios
    .request({
      url: '/some/url',
      method: 'get',
      params: {
        offset: 0,
        limit: 12,
        unknown: '???'
      },
      ...
    })
```

Must be converted to `/some/url?offset=0&limit=12&unknown=%3F%3F%3F`.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, i get that, just feel that wanna shorten the code a lil bit so that I won’t have to go through the trouble of writing: params: { offset, limit } in the parameters

Comment: @kyapwc parameters encoding is the standard behaviour of axios

Answer (score 6):

As there is no need to use query-string as axios does it automatically by putting the params into the request.

But still if you want to use the query-string package you can do it by this way.

Here is a short example which can give you somewhat idea of using **query-string**.

```js
import qs from 'qs'; (https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs)
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:3000/api/products`,
    params: (params) => {
        return qs.stringify(params, {offset: 0, limit: 12});
    },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`Axios` provides another handy yet powerful way to send your queryParams as object to http `GET` method.

You may change your request this way:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/products', {
    params: {
      offset: 0,
      limit: 12
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.$axios.get('/', {
    params: {},
    paramsSerializer: params => {
      return qs.stringify(params);
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use template literals, you need to use  the back-tick () not normal quotes.
**CODE:**

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/products${qs.parse({ offset: 0, limit: 12 })}`);
```

If you dont want to use back-ticks, you cannot use `${}` syntax.
Just do it like normal string interpolation works.

```
axios.get(‘http://localhost:3000/api/products'+qs.parse({ offset: 0, limit: 12 })});
```

Comment: I wrote a short comment about the backticks bro. Using mobile to post the question, the keyboard does not have backticks haha

Comment: Yeah, thats why I said use normal string interpolation. Because you cannot use ${} with normal quotes